# Gradle project refresh failed on domain connected computer

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, unc

I have installed Android Studio 0.5.6 on a Domain Connected Computer and I have set the .gradle and .AndroidStudioPreview folders to C:\Users\Dan\ by editing idea.properties and setting gradle Service Directory Path in settings.

The problem is I keep getting this error

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.EffectiveClassPath.findAvailableClasspathFiles(EffectiveClassPath.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.EffectiveClassPath.<init>(EffectiveClassPath.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.<init>(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.<init>(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
```

Anyone got any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your project settings go to Gradle and the service directory path would be using a UNC path e.g. \ ..

you need to change that to a local directory then all good.